# How to get result from activity without using onActivityResult

Tags: android, android-intent

I am invoking my camera to capture an image using the following intent :

```
Intent imageIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
```

Now if use `startActivityForResult()` , i am able to get the resultant data i.e. uri of the captured picture and then i can perform some operations on that picture in `onActivityResult()`.

My question is that is there any other way to get that resultant data other than going in `onActivityResult()`.

Answer (score 2):

> My question is that is there any other way to get that resultant data other than going in onActivityResult().

No, sorry. The only way to get results from `startActivityForResult()`, starting an activity that you did not write, is via `onActivityResult()`.

Comment: Actually, i m calling this capturing intent in a `click` action, and afture capturing the image, i need to come back in the same `click` action.

Comment: @FuthorcStack: Put the code that you want to "come back" to into `onActivityResult()`.

Comment: You cannot come back to that click action. Actions are started asynchronously and the only way to get the result of the Asynchronous request to the other activity is in onActivityResult(). If there is state that you need to keep in the click() action you will have to preserve it. Set a variable in your Activity and save and restore the state of that variable in the Activity lifecycle to have it when onActivityResult() is called.

Comment: @NickPalmer's answer is partially right. However, using the word `asynchronous` is not appropriate. It is not asynchronous. Both of them run on the UI thread and when you start the new activity, your current activity gets stopped. So it's synchronous.

Comment: Yeah, i think that is going to be the only solution for my problem.

Comment: @MiroMarkaravanes that is taking a very narrow view of what asynchronous means. Asynchronous is not JUST about what thread code is running on. I was using asynchronous in the sense that a callback is issued at a future undetermined time, rather than a result being returned from the startActivityForResult() call.

Comment: @MiroMarkaravanes See the apigee description of the difference: http://apigee.com/docs/content/asynchronous-vs-synchronous-calls Note also that several other bits of code, such as onPause(), are run in the context of the existing Activity BEFORE the next activity starts on the UI thread, so control is not immediately handed off to the next Activity.

Answer (score 0):

Yup to can try this hack...

1.You can query/listen [MediaStore](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.html) and check the timestamp of latest image.

2.compare the image creation timestamp with the launch time of camera Activity,if the difference very small there are very good chances the the user took the image with the camera activity which you launched.

Just to add this will only work when you want to select the image just clicked by the camera or the latest image created on the system.

If you are only interested in image captured by camera you came use android camera apis.

> The Android framework includes support for various cameras and camera
>   features available on devices, allowing you to capture pictures and
>   videos in your applications.

For more info refer [here](http://developer.android.com/training/camera/cameradirect.html)

Comment: This does not allow the user to pick an existing image, which is what the code shown in the question does. Please explain how your answer actually addresses the question.

Comment: @CommonsWare the first line says "I am invoking my camera to capture an image using the following intent"..so I presumed that he/she is only interested in camera

Comment: Good point, in which case the OP is using the wrong `Intent`. Use `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE` to invoke a camera app, not `ACTION_PICK`.